# OOP - Should a post delete itself?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

If I have a post class (example, a blog post), it will have a few methods:

- getReplies()
- getViews()
- logView()

etc...

But where does deletePost() go?  I would assume it should not go in the post class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

deletePost() would most likely go in the master of the Post class (perhaps Wall or BlogPage or something along those lines). Since the Wall would contain posts (and thereby have some sort of addPost() method, you would also include the deletePost() method there as well! Example (in rough Java) below:

```
public class Wall {
     ArrayList<Post> wallposts;
     public addPost(Post newpost) {
          this.wallposts.add(newpost);
     }
     public deletePost(Post p) {
          this.wallposts.remove(p);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using the Active Record pattern, then if you are talking about deleting from the database, it's fine to have a delete() method inside your Post class.

Are you using a DAO class to get your posts? then the delete should be there.

Answer (score 1):

The deletePost() should go in the Post Manager class. In here, you should call the Delete function of the Post Class.

Assuming that you have a Post Manager that contains all of your Posts, whenever you want to delete something, the Post Manager will tell the Post to delete itself. This allows the Post to handle everything about itself (delete any replies to the posts, comments, etc), things that the Post Manager should not know about. Using the code

```
 public class Post{
      .....
      public delete() {
         // Do database stuff here or any clean up that the Post needs to do....
      }
 }


 public class PostManager{
      ArrayList<Post> posts;
      ....
      public deletePost(Post p){
        p.delete();
      } 
  }
```

**EDIT**: To answer your question, yes, the Post should delete itself. Provided the Post Manager tells it to.